# Getting and modifying properties of Custom View Class in Android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-custom-view

I am a beginner in Android. I am using a custom view class, let's say CustomView which looks like:

```
class CustomView(context: Context?,attributeSet: AttributeSet) : View(context) {

    class CustomView constructor(context: Context?, attributeSet: AttributeSet){

    }
    var number = 1
}
```

I am inflating this view inside my view in main activity resource, like:

```
<com.example.myapp.CustomView
     android:id="@+id/custom_view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Now, what I want to do is, click a button on main activity and modify the value of number and also get the modified value of number in main activity.

Like, clicking a button in main activity, changing the value of number to 2 and displaying the modified value inside main activity.

Is it possible?

Comment: Just don't mark your `number` property as `private`.

Comment: done, but how do I get the value now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using simple setter and getter functions

```
class CustomView constructor(context: Context?, attributeSet: AttributeSet){
    
    var number = 1

    fun getNumber(){
        return number
    }

    fun setNumber(num: Int){
        number = num
    }
}
```

And calling them like

```
val customView: CustomView = findViewById(R.id.custom_view)
customView.setNumber(2)
var num = customView.getNumber()
```

With getter and setter, it will work just fine with private access modifier too.