# Update custom view custom properties programmatically

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-custom-view, android-custom-attributes

I have custom view named CustomView which has two custom attributes att1 and att2 defined.

Inside XML I can update the attributes easily like below:

```
<com.example.myapp.CustomView
     android:id="@+id/custom_view"
     app:att1="value_1"
     app:att2=value_2"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

But how do I update them programmatically?

Similar to this:

```
val customView: CustomView = findViewById(R.id.custom_view)
customView.att1 = "value_1"
customView.att2 = "value2"
```

Comment: Create Setters & Getter for the respective variables, invalidate after setting a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [@DarShan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6819340/darshan) in the comment, creating setter and getter and invalidating the view was the solution. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65429272/getting-and-modifying-properties-of-custom-view-class-in-android) question.